# Unable to Scroll Overflow Element in Next.js App after Integrating Lenis React Component

Tags: css, next.js

I recently integrated **Lenis React** component into my Next.js application, and since then, I've encountered an issue with scrolling an element with the "overflow-scroll" class on my page. Prior to integrating the Lenis component, scrolling worked seamlessly.
this are the css styles `overflow-y-scroll pr-[17px] box-content`

- Tried using the scrollArea from Mantine as well, but the problem persists.
- Tried to focus on mouseOver.
- Tried implementing my own logic for scrolling

Code

```
useEffect(() => {
    const element = carouselContainerRef.current;

    const handleMouseMove = (event) => {
      if (!isScrolling) return;

      // Simplified calculations since we're using the ref directly
      const containerRect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
      const deltaY = event.clientY - containerRect.top;

      const maxScrollTop = element.scrollHeight - element.clientHeight;
      const newScrollTop = Math.min(Math.max(0, deltaY), maxScrollTop);

      element.scrollTop = newScrollTop;
    };

    if (element) {
      element.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
    }
    return () => {
      if (element) {
        element.addEventListener('mousemove', handleMouseMove);
      }
    };
}, [isScrolling]);
```

but this scrolls based on mouse position. (not what i am searching for).

Despite these efforts, I'm still unable to scroll the overflow element. How can I troubleshoot and resolve this issue? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!